# Django : get data and edit in the same form, edit in one place

Tags: python, html, django

I've been working to make an edit form where shows data saved in db and user can edit it like jsp model and view. When user click button it shows add form but all the relevant information in db is already filled up in the form, so user can modifying old data and once they click submit button it redirect to main.
I succeeded to display a form when user click edit button but failed to get data.

this is views.py

```
@login_required
def update_article(request, article_no):
   article = get_object_or_404(Article, no=article_no)
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=article)
       if form.is_valid():
          post = form.save(commit=False)
          post.save()
          return redirect('blog.views.detail', no=article.no)
   else:
       form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
   return render(request, 'blog/update_article.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^update_article/(?P<article_no>[0-9]+)/$', views.update_article, name='update_article'),
```

update_article.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="create_article.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'blog/form_template.html' %}
       <button type="submit" class="button-primary">submit</button>

 </form>
 <a href="{% url 'blog:home' %}" class="button button-primary">list</a>

{% endblock %}
```

detail.html
This is part of the page send users to update_article.html

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:update_article' item.no %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="no" value="{{ item.no }}" />
 <button type="submit" class="button-primary">edit</button>
 </form>
```

form_template.html

```
  {% for field in form %}
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">{{ field.label_tag }</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
 </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `update_article` views
pass `article` object with form

`return render(request, 'blog/update_article.html', {'form': form, 'article': article})`

and then form in html page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="create_article.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'blog/form_template.html' %}
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="title" value="{{article.title}}"/>
    <textarea class="u-full-width" name="content" value="{{article.content}}"></textarea>
       <button type="submit" class="button-primary">등록</button>

 </form>
```

I think this would help your problem

also I guess your action link is not valid